# Order Status Email Fields... which box is being used?

Tags: expresso-store

https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/settings_order_statuses.html

There are the two boxes containing email templates, which box should contain the emails I want to send?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left panel is where you search for/browse the available emails, and the right panel is where the email(s) you've selected appear.

Generally in all EE add-ons with split-select interfaces like this, the left panel is the source, and the right panel is the selection (see the native Relationships field and Playa as examples).

Comment: Thanks, was just unclear because the emails weren't being delivered (communicate tool sent without error) so didn't know if I was misunderstanding this.  

If anyone else ever sees this and has the same train as thought as me, I solved the email delivery issue using Escort with Mandrill.